# LDAP no longer available - how can I log into SugarCRM?

Tags: ldap, sugarcrm

I've restored a SugarCRM installation to a new host where previous LDAP services are not available, and will not be recreated.

Of course, I cannot log in now.

Can I disable LDAP via config files, and get logged in somehow? (I'm not concerned about retaining old users or history.)

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off LDAP in the config table in the database with this query:

```
UPDATE config SET value=0 WHERE category='system' AND name='ldap_enabled';
```